# Full text search with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I have two tables:

```
FirstTable
===============================
Id int primary key identity ,
Text varchar(4000)


Phrase
===============================
Id int primary key identity ,
Text varchar(4000) ,
ExcludingText varchar(4000)
```

I need to filter rows from first table that contain value from `Text` column of **Phrase** table and NOT include `ExcludedText` value for same row.

Between tables does not exist any relationship, for every row from `FirstTable` I must check every existing combination (include Text, not include ExcludedText).

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically construct a full text query based on the contents of your `Phrase` table.

```
declare @FullTextCondition as varchar(max)
set @FullTextCondition = STUFF(
    (
        SELECT '"' + Text + '" AND NOT "' + ExcludingText + '" AND '
        FROM Phrase 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),
    1, 0, ''
)

-- remove trailing ' AND '
set @FullTextCondition = SUBSTRING(@FullTextCondition, 0, LEN(@FullTextCondition) - 3)

-- now perform your full text search
SELECT *
FROM FirstTable
WHERE CONTAINS(*, @FullTextCondition)
```

So for example if your `Phrase` table has this data:

```
Id  Text       ExcludingText
-------------------------------------
1   good       bad
2   ok         not ok
```

Then your full text query (`@FullTextCondition`) will look like this:

```
'"good" AND NOT "bad" AND "ok" AND NOT "not ok"'
```

Of course, consider the size of your `Phrase` table. If it is very large then it will impact the performance